# Python: get type and convert to this type

Tags: python, type-conversion

I'm new at Python. I have an object with some fields and I have a list of field names and values, but all the values in this list are strings. I need to find an object field and assign the value. I already found out how to find the field. However, I have a problem with type conversion.

For example:

```
class SomeEntity:

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.some_attr = {}


 def applyValues(entity, list_of_values):
     for key, value in list_of_values:
         if hasattr(entity, key):
             setattr(entity, key, value) # !!! here is the problem to convert to type
```

i need something like this :

```
x = getattr(entity, key)
type_attr = type(x)
converted = type_attr(value)
setattr(entity, key, converted)
```

How I can do this? Or can I use some other way?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of one of the many, many questions for which the accepted answer is "use a dictionary instead".

Comment: I cant use dictionary instead of class because I have this class generated from protobuf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value strings are valid Python literals you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely evaluate those strings into Python objects.

```
import ast

class SomeEntity:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.some_attr = {}

def apply_values(entity, list_of_values):
    for key, value in list_of_values:
        if hasattr(entity, key):
            converted = ast.literal_eval(value)
            setattr(entity, key, converted)

entity = SomeEntity()

attr_list = [
    ('id', '42'), 
    ('name', '"the entity"'), 
    ('some_attr', '{"one": 1, "two": 2}'),
]
apply_values(entity, attr_list)

x = entity.id
print(x, type(x))
x = entity.name
print(x, type(x))
x = entity.some_attr
print(x, type(x))
```

**output**

```
42 <class 'int'>
the entity <class 'str'>
{'one': 1, 'two': 2} <class 'dict'>
```

---

Note that we can also put the attribute name & value strings into a `dict`:

```
attr_dict = {
    'id': '42', 
    'name': '"the entity"', 
    'some_attr': '{"one": 1, "two": 2}'
}

apply_values(entity, attr_dict.items())
```

---

As Alfe mentions in the comments, that code ignores the type of the entity's attributes. Here's a modified version that takes the existing attribute types into account.

```
import ast

class SomeEntity:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.some_attr = {}
        self.level = 0.0

def apply_values(entity, list_of_values):
    for key, value in list_of_values:
        if hasattr(entity, key):
            type_attr = type(getattr(entity, key))
            converted = type_attr(ast.literal_eval(value))
            setattr(entity, key, converted)

entity = SomeEntity()

attr_dict = {
    'id': '42', 
    'name': '"the entity"', 
    'some_attr': '{"one": 1, "two": 2}',
    'level': '5',
}

apply_values(entity, attr_dict.items())

for k, v in entity.__dict__.items():
    print(repr(k), repr(v), type(v))
```

**output**

```
'id' 42 <class 'int'>
'name' 'the entity' <class 'str'>
'some_attr' {'one': 1, 'two': 2} <class 'dict'>
'level' 5.0 <class 'float'>
```

Comment: This will put an `int` for input `"5"` into a variable which is supposed to hold a `float`.  But I guess in most cases this does not pose any problem. ⁺¹ for using `ast.literal_eval()` even though it clearly is beyond OP's level.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it wokrs perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

Fixing a lot of bugs in Garjy's solution:

```
converted = eval(value)
```

Maybe you want to convert it explicitly afterwards to the correct type:

```
converted type(getattr(entity, key))(eval(value))
```

So completely in one line:

```
setattr(entity, key, type(getattr(entity, key))(eval(value)))
```